# I'd like to have badge "growing daemon". My reputation struck 13

Tags: feature-request, badges

Such kind of badges could be funny.

Comment: I'd like the moon on a stick. Ideally a nice hardwood stick. Perhaps teak, but I'm willing to be flexible. The stick probably shouldn't be too flexible that said, as it will after all be supporting the moon.

Comment: It's a pity that you disagree. You have really good opportunity to look demonically soon with 666 o 13 on meta.

Comment: why do I want to be demonic? I'd much rather be angelic.

Answer (score 6):

Badges are there to encourage growth and help nurture the community by rewarding active users for their efforts. As such, I'd imagine to some extent such throw-away "funny" badges would somewhat de-value the experience.

Comment: upvoting partly because I agree, but also because @middaparka only needs one more upvote to get rep 666... maybe in line for this badge then?  ;)

Comment: Upvoting for 666 rep... Ding! http://i.imgur.com/qOu0j.png

Comment: I *was* going to upvote, too.  But it's much better to have him stuck at **666**.  (Kinda like how Major Major Major Major couldn't be promoted or demoted.)

Comment: @Spudley @Pollyanna - you've both gone very, very, wrong. :-)

Comment: I'll do my best to avoid meta so as it keep this glorious reputation figure intact. :-)

Comment: @middaparka:  @Spudley and @Pollyanna are very, very right... and you obviously agree ;-)

Comment: @jae Just as long as nobody upvotes *anything* I do here on meta, it'll all be cool. :-)

Comment: Removed my upvote to get you back to 666. ;-D

Comment: @Pollyanna Oh well, at least you captured the moment. (I'll treasure that PNG forever.) :-)

Comment: @middaparka Ah well.  There's nothing to do now, except push you up towards 0x666.

Answer (score 2):

We're reserving that badge for the first person to reach 666,666,666 reputation.

Comment: Skeet is on his way.

Comment: Will he then not rather be the Anti-Anti-Anti-Christ?  Hmmm, of *course*! ;-)