# Why is the same user identified with two different names on the same question?

Tags: bug, community-wiki, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do old usernames stick to CW posts by design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/do-old-usernames-stick-to-cw-posts-by-design)

I've read that it may exist a [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) on the username presented due to [denormalized fields](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47522/184576) (*mentioned on Apr 22 '10 at 19:30*), but on that same [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47474/184576), there's an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110197/184576) that mentions the resolution of this issue (*answered on Oct 24 '11 at 21:22*):

> Some time in mid or late 2011, a change was made that affected this behavior. Current names are now shown on some old posts, such as the one I used as the example in the question...

The referred "old post" is a community wiki, just like this one:

[image: Print-Screen of: Reward finding duplicate questions - +10, +2, -5]

This community wiki was asked on [May 10 '11 at 10:43](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/90620/1), and by the revisions history the user is referred with the name `Discount Gucci Handbags`.

The comment on [May 10 '11 at 11:14](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5#comment225684_90620) refers to the `Discount Gucci Handbags` username.

Currently this user has the `Discount Gucci Handbags` username.

So, I was wondering why the `Pekka` username persists instead of `Discount Gucci Handbags`?

Comment: Since you've read the other post where this is listed [meta-tag:status-bydesign], I'm not entirely sure what you're confused by. The answer that talks about this being resolved isn't correct for the general case - the name *will* update, under a specific set of circumstances, but in general the expected behaviour is what Jeff described. Comments and revisions are rendered on-demand, so the associated (linked) user name in those cases is always up-to-date.

Comment: @TimStone My confusion relates to the name from Lord Torgamus to Popular Demand got updated and the name Pekka to Discount Gucci Handbags didn't. Is there any "guide-lines" as to what "specific set of circumstances" are we talking about?

Comment: @PopularDemand Since your example question technically did have multiple editors, I'm beginning to think that the name (and the percentage edited, by association) is only denormalized in the case where multiple editors touched the *body* of the post, but I haven't tried to confirm that yet.

Comment: @PopularDemand So, perhaps we need synonym for usernames to keep track and properly identify users across the system :)

Comment: @Zuul You mean user ID?  Look at the url for your profile to see yours.  That won't change, even if you change your name.

Comment: @Servy No I mean the username -> "Zuul", not the userID -> "184576". what visually identifies the user is its username. The comment to Popular Demand was sarcastic. The appropriate thing to happen would be to have the username ALWAYS updated.

Comment: @Servy Visually I can't relate a question from Lord Torgamus to the username Popular Demand. I'll be under the belief that they are two different users. I've noticed this to be wrong with Pekka since I know about is "famous" Discount Gucci Handbags.

Comment: You may also be interested in [Keep short history of user display names](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28924/keep-short-history-of-user-display-names) and the questions in its Linked and Related lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are point-by-point replies to your statements:

> This community wiki was asked on May 10 '11 at 10:43, and by the revisions history the user is referred with the name Discount Gucci Handbags.

Revision histories always show current usernames. (This was not always the case.)

> The comment on May 10 '11 at 11:14 refers to the Discount Gucci Handbags username.

Comment author fields always show current usernames.

> Currently this user has the Discount Gucci Handbags username.

Okay, this one doesn't really need a reply.

> So, I was wondering why the Pekka username persists instead of Discount Gucci Handbags?

Finally, the interesting question. In a comment under one of the answers you linked to, [Grace Note suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/do-old-usernames-stick-to-cw-posts-by-design#comment285100_110197) that old names are "only present if there are multiple revisions/users." For reference, she provided a link to Adam Davis's wiki posts. Adam is a good test case for two reasons: he was known by the name Pollyanna for a long time, and he has a lot of CW posts under his belt.

My analysis shows that Grace was right. The current behavior is that **when *any* user edits a CW answer, the old username "sticks"; otherwise, the new username appears**. This agrees with [the post you were looking at](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/90620/revisions?page=2). Note that the rule does **not** hold for CW questions.

Here are some data. Most of these columns turned out to be irrelevant; the two big ones are Name and Editor history.

```
╔═══════╦══════╦══════╦══════════════════╦═══════╦════════════╦════════════╦═════════════╦════════════════╦═══════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════╗  
║ Post  ║ Type ║ Name ║  Editor history  ║ Body  ║ Post date  ║ Edit date  ║ Rev made CW ║  How made CW   ║ Q CW? ║                      Misc                       ║  
╠═══════╬══════╬══════╬══════════════════╬═══════╬════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╣  
║ 76000 ║ Ans  ║ P    ║ AD AD            ║ Yes   ║ Jan 22 '11 ║ Mar 4 '11  ║ rev 1       ║ manual         ║ no    ║                                                 ║  
║ 81466 ║ Ans  ║ AD   ║ AD               ║ N/A   ║ Mar 3 '11  ║ N/A        ║ auto        ║ Q started CW   ║ yes   ║                                                 ║  
║ 81378 ║ Ans  ║ P    ║ AD AD            ║ Yes   ║ Mar 2 '11  ║ Mar 2 '11  ║ auto        ║ Q started CW   ║ yes   ║                                                 ║  
║ 81376 ║ Ans  ║ AD   ║ AD               ║ N/A   ║ Mar 2 '11  ║ N/A        ║ auto        ║ Q started CW   ║ yes   ║                                                 ║  
║ 81375 ║ Ans  ║ AD   ║ AD               ║ N/A   ║ Mar 2 '11  ║ N/A        ║ auto        ║ Q started CW   ║ yes   ║                                                 ║  
║ 81293 ║ Ans  ║ AD   ║ AD               ║ N/A   ║ Mar 2 '11  ║ N/A        ║ auto        ║ Q started CW   ║ yes   ║                                                 ║  
║ 81272 ║ Ans  ║ AD   ║ AD               ║ N/A   ║ Mar 2 '11  ║ N/A        ║ auto        ║ Q started CW   ║ yes   ║                                                 ║  
║ 81271 ║ Ans  ║ AD   ║ AD               ║ N/A   ║ Mar 2 '11  ║ N/A        ║ auto        ║ Q started CW   ║ yes   ║                                                 ║  
║ 81269 ║ Ans  ║ AD   ║ AD               ║ N/A   ║ Mar 2 '11  ║ N/A        ║ auto        ║ Q started CW   ║ yes   ║                                                 ║  
║ 78188 ║ Ans  ║ AD   ║ AD               ║ N/A   ║ Feb 6 '11  ║ N/A        ║ after rev 1 ║ mod made Q CW  ║ yes   ║                                                 ║  
║ 77795 ║ Qst  ║ AD   ║ AD AD            ║ Yes   ║ Feb 3 '11  ║ Feb 3 '11  ║ after rev 2 ║ mod            ║ N/A   ║                                                 ║  
║ 77796 ║ Ans  ║ P    ║ AD oth oth       ║ Yes   ║ Feb 3 '11  ║ Feb 3 '11  ║ auto?       ║ mod made Q CW? ║ yes?  ║                                                 ║  
║ 76717 ║ Ans  ║ P    ║ AD AD oth oth AD ║ Yes   ║ Jan 27 '11 ║ Jan 27 '11 ║ auto        ║ Q started CW   ║ yes   ║                                                 ║  
║ 75963 ║ Ans  ║ AD   ║ AD               ║ N/A   ║ Jan 22 '11 ║ N/A        ║ after rev 1 ║ manual         ║ no    ║ bounty                                          ║  
║ 58975 ║ Ans  ║ AD   ║ Anon             ║ N/A   ║ Oct 29 '09 ║ N/A        ║ auto?       ║ ?              ║ yes   ║ migrated from SO; rev hist shows author as anon ║  
║ 29652 ║ Ans  ║ AD   ║ AD               ║ Yes   ║ Nov 5 '09  ║ Nov 5 '09  ║ auto        ║ Q started CW   ║ yes   ║                                                 ║  
║ 28456 ║ Ans  ║ P    ║ AD oth           ║ Yes   ║ Nov 3 '09  ║ Nov 3 '09  ║ auto        ║ Q started CW   ║ yes   ║                                                 ║  
║ 28191 ║ Ans  ║ P    ║ AD oth           ║ Yes   ║ Nov 2 '09  ║ Nov 2 '09  ║ auto        ║ Q started CW   ║ yes   ║                                                 ║  
║  8805 ║ Ans  ║ AD   ║ AD               ║ N/A   ║ Mar 30 '09 ║ N/A        ║ auto        ║ Q had >30 ans  ║ yes   ║ migrated from SO; later closed/protected        ║  
╚═══════╩══════╩══════╩══════════════════╩═══════╩════════════╩════════════╩═════════════╩════════════════╩═══════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I wasn't able to test [Tim's theory about a body edit being required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140264/why-is-the-same-user-identified-with-two-different-names-on-the-same-question/140311#comment395820_140264), but it seems reasonable. There have been other issues discussed on MSO where that has mattered.

If you [sort Adam's wiki posts by "active"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&pagesize=50&q=user%3a2915%20wiki%3a1), you may notice that everything with activity more recent than March 8, 2011 appears with the new name. That's (about) the date Adam changed his name ([source one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82336/broken-ui-hover-popup-from-hovering-over-tags-hides-tags-textbox#comment201165_82336), [source two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82217/id-like-to-have-badge-growing-daemon-my-reputation-struck-13/82218#comment200831_82218)).

Comment: I've gone through your detailled answer. Tks for the clarification on this subject. I still strongly believe that a username present anywhere on the system should always be the current username. Otherwise, we need to access the user profile page to see actually who he is.

Answer (score 4):

See [Old usernames stick to Community Wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/do-old-usernames-stick-to-cw-posts-by-design) ; the comment is updated with the current user name in this case, while the Community Wiki post's username is not. It's a little confusing but it seems there's no plan to change how it's handled.

Comment: Tks for your input on this subject. I've gone with the answer from Popular Demand due to the detailed information provided.